# CSS3 animation not working in webkit

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, animation, preloader

I have an animation that works perfectly fine in all browsers but the webkit ones. In webkit it shows only 1 circle rotating, while others work fine with all 5 circles. The animation preview is here - http://cssload.net/windows8.html

what is wrong with the code? please, help...

Comment: My safari just opened 5 circles rotating exactly like Firefox. The problem is specific to chrome, my chrome just showed 1 circle as you stated

Comment: My chrome only shows one _stationary_ circle, fading out once in a while.

Comment: I remember Chrome having problems displaying a demo of a 3d cloud. The individual elements got clipped with the clipping plane moving on cloud rotation. Perhaps this is a clipping issue.

Comment: Yes, just installed safari and it's really working fine in it... does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did it!

The problem was the opacity from your innerball class, in google-chrome they needed to be set in all keyframes. This approach didn't break the effect for safari.

```
@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        }

    7% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-origin:0%;
        }

   30% {
        opacity: 1;  
        -webkit-transform:rotate(410deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -webkit-origin:7%;
        }

    39% {
        opacity: 1;  
        -webkit-transform: rotate(645deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-origin:30%;
        }

    70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(770deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-origin:39%;    
        }

    75% {
        opacity: 1; 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -webkit-origin:70%;    
        }

    76% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(900deg);
        }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg);
        }

}
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q4wtm/27/

Comment: You are welcome! And thank you btw, otherwise I'd never know that the css3 implementation from google-chrome and safari webkit somehow differs